# MySQL Select based on time range

Tags: mysql, time

I have a database of slots which have a start time and end time ( Date also but that is by the by ). So some example results of booked slots in the database would be:

```
----------------------------------
start_time        -  end_time    -
----------------------------------
09:00                15:00
17:00                18:00
19:00                21:00
----------------------------------
```

So lets say I want to check if availability of the following times:

```
09:00 - 10:00 - ( This is Unavailable in the results above )
18:00 - 19:00 - ( Available based on the results above )
```

What would be an MySQL query to handle this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM slots WHERE end_time>=:from AND start_time<=:to

Comment: @MauricePerry — That won't work if the from and to overlap with but aren't entirely within an existing appointment.

Comment: @Quentin can you think of an example?

Comment: @MauricePerry — Start time 14:00, End time 15:30

Comment: @Quentin the first would match

Comment: @Quentin no, you're right

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *,
       NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                    FROM timeslot
                    WHERE timeslot.time_start < timerange.time_end
                      AND timerange.time_start < timeslot.time_end ) is_available
FROM timerange
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=431f8a2fa0331482359587ccace31a59)

Comment: Note that bookings often operate an 'open-close' policy (I think they call it that, but I don't know why) wherein one of the comparisons is always 'or equal to'.

Comment: Incidentally, while obviously logically identical, I do find `a.start < b.end AND a.end > b.start` slightly easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Strawberry I think "any start less than another end" is more clear and easy to remember.

Comment: @Strawberry *one of the comparisons is always 'or equal to'.* I doubt that adjacency prevents booking. If not some deviation must be added.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slots WHERE end_time>:from AND start_time<:to
```

If it returns zero, you're good to go.

Examples:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slots WHERE end_time>'09:00' AND start_time<'10:00'
```

-> 1: Unavailable

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slots WHERE end_time>'18:00' AND start_time<'19:00'
```

-> 0: Available

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slots WHERE end_time>'14:30' AND start_time<'15:30'
```

-> 1: Unavailable

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slots WHERE end_time>'16:30' AND start_time<'17:30'
```

-> 1: Unavailable